# JavaScript console output issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a very basic "create your own adventure" in JavaScript and cannot get the output that I am wanting.

My Code:

```js
var enter = confirm("You are outside a forest cabin. Press OK to enter.");

if (enter) {
  //go into the cabin
  var bowl = prompt("You see three bowls of porridge. Eat bowl 1, 2, or 3?")
  if (bowl == 1) {
    console.log("It's too hot! THE END");
  } else if (bowl == 2) {
    console.log("It's too cold! THE END");
  } else {
    console.log("It's delicious.");

    var hours = "The porridge makes you sleepy. Nap for how many hours?";
    var sleep = prompt(hours);
    sleep = Number(sleep);

    if (sleep <= 2) {
      console.log("You wake just in time, and scamper away!");
    } else {
      console.log("You sleep to late, and are eaten by hungry bears.");
    }
    console.log("THE END.");

  }
} else {
  //didn't go in
  console.log("And that's the world's shortest fable. THE END.")
}
```

The code works when I run it however the issue is with the output. When I type in 1 for the porridge question, when prompted, it stops the code and doesn't say "It's too hot! THE END". 
Is there something that I need to add that will display "It's too hot! THE END" or any of the console.log() output in the browser?

EDIT: I was expecting it to POP UP like it was doing with Prompt. 
Thank you for those that told me about alert! It is working Great!

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Are you checking your console? It's working for me.

Comment: Works ok! you are not showing any alert for the porridge

Comment: `console.log()` as the name says, logs to the **console**. If you don't know what that is, Google how to open the web developer tools in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

It does work. Are you looking at the console? If you're expecting a popup like `prompt` and `confirm`, use `alert` instead of `console.log`.